# How to get ID of button when clicked while it is looped

Tags: javascript, php, html

[i am using this loop to select existing data from database table and assigning them to html  element. it works fine but I have no idea how to select its ID when the button is clicked.

I tried using document.GetElementByID but cannot choose particular ID when the button is clicked. Any suggestions on how to get the ID Of that button when it is clicked using javascript?

[image]

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
$stmnt = "select * from tbl_category"; 
$run = $con->query($stmnt);
$num=$run->num_rows;
if($num>0)
{
while($data = $run->fetch_array()){
$btn1 = $data['id']; 
echo $btn1;
?>  
<button id="<?php $btn1;?>" class="btn"><?php echo $data['category']; ?>
</button>
<?php
}
}
?>`
```

Comment: Can you write more of your code? js?

Comment: also show your html

Comment: `alert($(this).attr('id'));`

Comment: sorry. my first time asking a question. but your answer helped. now it works fine. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).attr("id");
});
```

Or alternatively you can also use prop() method:

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).prop("id");
});
```

for documentation you can reff:
https://api.jquery.com/attr/
https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Or `this.getAttribute('id')` without `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript function:

```
<button id="<?php $btn1;?>" class="btn" onclick="javascript:get_buttonid(this);"><?php echo $data['category']; ?>
    </button>
    <script>
    function get_buttonid(ths){
        alert(ths.id);
    }   
    </script>
```